# echo html variable, that includes a php include

Tags: php, html

I have this issue. I have HTML code stored in the database. I read it, and I display it in my pages using echo  $page_content;

I want to add somewhere in the middle of this HTML code a php include. Something like this:
 Inside this file I have also html code which is basically the country options for a select:

```
<option selected="selected" value="">Choose...</option>
<option value="AFGHANISTAN">AFGHANISTAN</option>
<option value="ALBANIA">ALBANIA</option>
<option value="ALGERIA">ALGERIA</option>
<option value="AMERICAN SAMOA">AMERICAN SAMOA</option>
<option value="ANDORRA">ANDORRA</option>
<option value="ANGOLA">ANGOLA</option>
etc etc
```

Until now I have hard-coded all the countries in many places, which I don't like.

But this is not displayed at all when i do my 
     echo  $page_content;

Comment: You want to bring the variable to global scope? Or what do you want?

Comment: How to add PHP code?, Can you show your code?

Comment: If you're storing PHP you want to execute in your database, then you're doing something wrong. I'd stop and rethink your design rather then trying to get this working.

Comment: Weh I'm tired. Oh well maybe I'll just keep this around.. comment: I suggest you use an absolute path in the `include` statement. For example you could define the root of your application using `define( 'DIR_ROOT', dirname( __FILE__ ) );` in a file in the highest directory of your site, for example a `config.php` file (which has to be included/required by all other pages). Then you use this in your include calls. As such: `include( DIR_ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'countries.php' );`

Comment: thanks to all for your suggestions. I know the architecture is terrible, but I inherited it from someone else and I am trying to make the best of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the easiest ways is to use tokens that get replaced with the content.

This can avoid the use of eval - which is not recommended ane would get me down voted by the herd.

For example:

HTML CODE

```
Hello, _TOKEN2_!
```

You can then use string replace functions to replace the TOKEN2 (the underscores are there but seemed to disappear here) with whatever you want:

```
str_replace("_TOKEN2_","World",$page_content);
```

And so on, you get the idea.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you look into using something like Smarty to separate you're PHP and layout.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it... Any templating language and store it (the template) in DB.

Comment: Brian i see many articles about smarty templates etc and I don't know much. Can you give me an example please of how this applies in my case? basically i add {php} tags around my include, but still it shows nothing. Is there something I need to do fro smarty to work?